# mysql query using multiple OR statements

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a better way than this?

```
SELECT * FROM tagcloud 
WHERE (usertag_tag = 1 
OR usertag_tag = 2 
OR usertag_tag = 3    
OR usertag_tag = 4)
```

What if I want to add more tags to the query, do I keep adding OR statements?

Comment: can you use a not equal to?  for example if you have 6 tags and only want 1-5, the use `usertag_tag !=6`

Comment: Use `usertag_tag IN(1,2,3,4,5)` which is standard SQL and will function like an `OR` chain.

Comment: The [IN() operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a simple version

```
 SELECT * FROM tagcloud 
WHERE usertag_tag in (1,2,3,4);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IN statement:

```
SELECT * FROM tagcloud WHERE user_tag IN(1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like 
    SELECT * FROM tagcloud 
    WHERE usertag_tag in (1, 2, 3, 4).

Answer (score 0):

You should prepare a list and make a select from it:

```
$tags = array( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
$query = "SELECT * FROM tagcloud WHERE usertag_tag IN (" . implode( ',', $tags ) . ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

IN can be used but I guess the ids that you are inserting are dynamic (can be from another table)
so you may use

```
 SELECT * FROM tagcloud 
 WHERE usertag_tag in (select id from the_other_table)
```

if not then this is okay

```
 SELECT * FROM tagcloud 
 WHERE usertag_tag in (1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array like this,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tagcloud WHERE user_tag IN ";  

$j = 6;

for($i = 0; $i< $j; $i++){
$queryArray[] .= "('". $i. "')";
}

$sql .= implode(',', $queryArray);
```

Just change `j` to your desired value.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL IN

```
SELECT * FROM tagcloud 
WHERE (usertag_tag = 1 
OR usertag_tag = 2 
OR usertag_tag = 3    
OR usertag_tag = 4)

/* You are checking whether usertag_tag is either 1, 2, 3 OR 4*/
```

Is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM tagcloud 
WHERE (usertag_tag IN (1, 2, 3, 4))
/* You are checking usertag_tag is one of the  values in the array given as 
array(1, 2, 3, 4)
If you want to add more values, just add elements to the array, that is it.
*/
```

**Explanation:**

If we are comparing single value, we use `=`.

If we need to find a rows with given field in one of the values (array of values), we use `IN`.

`MySQL IN` functions logically same as PHP's [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)